# How to implement this sorted array to binary search tree method

Tags: c#, binary-search-tree

Below is a method for a adding a sorted array into a binary search tree to allow the tree to be balanced. i was wondering how you could apply the method below into the MAIN in order to run and return a result.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // how to I implement the below method in the main ??
    }

    public virtual TreeNode sortedArrayToBST(int[] num)
    {
        if (num.Length == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }
        return sortedArrayToBST(num, 0, num.Length - 1);
    }
    public virtual TreeNode sortedArrayToBST(int[] num, int start, int end)
    {
        if (start > end)
        {
            return null;
        }

        int middle = start + (end - start) / 2;
        TreeNode root = new TreeNode(num[middle]);
        root.Left = sortedArrayToBST(num, start, middle - 1);
        root.Right = sortedArrayToBST(num, middle + 1, end);

        return root;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question appears to boil down to "How do I call a method?" - is this really the case, or is there something else missing from your question?

Comment: i am more having trouble with passing the array into the method. any thoughts??

Comment: It really sounds like you need to go and look at some C# tutorials to get a handle on the basics - providing that sort of information on Stack Overflow quickly becomes too broad and/or off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of integers and pass it to `sortedArrayToBST` method.
Do an inorder traversal with the `TreeNode` returned by this method.

Comment: How do you go about passing the array into the method??

Comment: In the second line of William's code, use:    TreeNode bst = sortedArrayToBST(SortedArray);

Comment: @Sam Can you upvote the answer/comment? Might help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
      object[] SortedArrray = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13 };
        TreeNode bst = new TreeNode(SortedArrray);
}
```